# How to avoid recreate an existing database using automatic Code First Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF6, and having an issue with database automatic migration. The database exists, and there is no schema nor data changes in the db. But for some strange reason, the application seems to trying to re-create an existing table in the db on machine reboot. And therefore cause errors. My questions are:

1. Why there will be automatic db migration when there is no db schema change? What triggered it?
2. How to fix it.

I use Include method to load entities like this, and the error occurs when I call it:

```
using (var context = new MyDataContext())
{
    return context.Students.Include("Courses");
}
```

In the `Student` class I have this navigation property:

```
public class Student
{    
...

   public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } 
}
```

In the Configuration.cs:

```
public Configuration()
{
   this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
   this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
...
```

I have also set the automatic database migration in the `MyDataContext` class like this:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDataContext, MyProject.DataModel.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

Currently, the issue is, 99% of the time, everything works just fine, and for some unknown reason, the following error occurs:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'Courses' in the database.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.b__2e()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.b__e()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path)

Any helps are appreciated!
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with an existing database, I suggest you check this page:[Code First Migrations with an existing database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn579398). There you are going to see it's necessary to do these two steps first before making any changes to your model:

1. Run the `Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges` command in
   Package Manager Console. This creates an empty migration with the
   current model as a snapshot.
2. Run the `Update-Database` command in Package Manager Console. This
   will apply the InitialCreate migration to the database. Since the
   actual migration doesn’t contain any changes, it will simply add a
   row to the `__MigrationHistory` table indicating that this migration
   has already been applied.

When you run the app using automatic migrations, if it’s doing any type of data initialization, it will check the `__MigrationHistory` table to see if the database needs to be updated.If there’s no `__MigrationHistory` table (which there won’t be in an existing database), the model won’t be verified against the database with automatic migrations. So you need to get that table into your existing database.To do that you need to follow the steps that I describe above.  When you run `Update-Database` command it will execute the `Up` method in the initial migration, which has no effect on the database. And it will create the `__MigrationHistory` table in your database based on the current state of the model. That way, if you are using automatic migrations, next time Code First does db initialization, it will compare the current model to the one stored in the `__MigrationHistory` to determine if the database needs to be migrated/updated.

Comment: Thanks for re-formatting my post. 
Maybe its confusing when I said the database exists. The database was created by EF, and and there is a __MigrationHistory table in the db. There is no schema, no data model change neither. Nothing need to be migrated.
The issue is: When .Include("Courses"); is called, exception was thrown: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'Courses' in the database.

Comment: Hello @littlemoli , the problem is that exception is throwed when the DB already exist. Anyway try to run the steps that I recommend you to stablish an initial point

Answer (score 0):

It would probably work if you do a trick.

Step 1: Using Package Manager Console to run Update_Database with temporary empty database.

Step 2: Try to get table __HistoryMigration from the temporary database to create and copy to table in your existing database.