# Stop EF from trying to create initial DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

So I successfully got my solution to create and initialize the Identity database. The problem now is, as I am working on it I keep getting this error

```
Cannot create file 'C:\Webs\SomeScheduler\SomeScheduler\App_Data\SomeSchedulerUsers.mdf' 
because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in 
the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot create file 
'C:\Webs\SomeScheduler\SomeScheduler\App_Data\SomeSchedulerUsers.mdf' 
because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

I know that it already exists, that is what I want. 
How do I stop it from trying to re-create it every time I try to run my code as I develop this site?

As always, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following line to your context constructor

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextClass>(null);
```

This should be enough.

But if you want to create the database only if it doesn't exists and correctly configure migrations, take a look at this question [How to avoid recreate an existing database using automatic Code First Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28618257/how-to-avoid-recreate-an-existing-database-using-automatic-code-first-migration)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with adding this

```xml
<contexts> 
 <context type="Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly" disableDatabaseInitialization="true" /> 
</contexts>
```

to your Web.config. Of course changing `Blogging.BlogContext, MyAssembly` to more accurately reflect your model.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606#Initializers)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try in response to that message is to look in Server Explorer in VS and right-click the database. If the `Detach Database` menu item is not disabled then click on that. That solved the problem for me when I was getting those messages.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie and this is my first post on this site, but I hope my post will help someone. I have the same message and for a long time I could not understand what is going on.

> Cannot create file '' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

I created an asp.net mvc project with an ms sql database and Entity Framework (code first). After creating the database, I immediately opened MS SQL Server Management Studio and added the database. After closing and reopening Visual Studio I always saw the same error (if I don't close VS everything works correctly). It turned out to be caused by connection to MS SQL Server Management Studio. It's not enough to close the program, or to disable the connection.
Here's what needs to be done.
[MS SQL SMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvdEY.jpg)

After Taking Offline, the problem immediately disappears. I don't know what it's related to (my knowledge is not enough), but I hope I helped.
I hope this helps someone.